# How to execute command from php (apache) in raspbian

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian, putty

I have RaspberryPi3, with raspbian. I am using [PiFmRds](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds) library to play sounds, and trying to control it from internet. I launched apache with this code in index.php:

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    exec('sox -t mp3 /home/tests/PiFmRds/music/Kairos.mp3 -t wav -  | sudo /home/tests/PiFmRds/src/pi_fm_rds - freq 98.0  -rt Track_name -ps ChillPi -audio -');
?>
```

Simple commands like 'ls -l' worked, but after this command nothing happens. What can be wrong? Maybe its permision issue?

P.S. putting this command to terminal works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the optional output to determine the error...most likely permission, current directory or user settings...think if the phone user account is the same as the one you are testing with on the console

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php